# Erro de tipo em update Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Está aparecendo o **erro**:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() must be of the type
>   array, object given, called in
>   /var/www/html/laravel/app/Http/Controllers/PropertyController.php on
>   line 89

*Controller:*

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Property;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $properties = Property::all();
    return view('/property/index')->with('properties', $properties);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('/property/create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $property = new Property;
    $property->nome = $request->nome;
    $property->proprietario = $request->proprietario;
    $property->valor = $request->valor;
    $property->save();
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@create');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    return view('/property/edit')->with('property', $property);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->update($request);
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $property->delete();
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}
}
```

*`Route:`*

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('auth/login');
});

Route::get('property/index', 'PropertyController@index'); 
Route::get('property/create', 'PropertyController@create');
Route::post('property/store', 'PropertyController@store');
Route::get('property/show', 'PropertyController@show');
Route::get('property/edit/{id}', 'PropertyController@edit');
Route::post('property/update/{id}', 'PropertyController@update');
Route::get('property/destroy/{id}', 'PropertyController@destroy');
```

*`Form:`*

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')


<form method="post" action="/property/update/{{$property->id}}"       class="container">

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" value=" {{$property->nome}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Proprietário</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="proprietario" value="{{$property->proprietario}}">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Valor</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor" value=" {{$property->valor}}">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Alterar</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do seu código, que estava sendo passado uma classe [`Request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#accessing-the-request), mas, o método requer um `array` com valores faltou chamar `$request->all()` e faltou configurar o seu model com [**fillable**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) que é o `array` de campos que podem ser atualizado ou criado (`create`).

No [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) existem formas de fazer atualizações na tabela:

*Model Property*

```
class Property
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = array('valor','proprietario','nome');
}
```

---

*1) Maneira:*

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    if ($property)
    {
        $property->fill($request->except(['_token'])); 
        $property->save();
    }
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}
```

nesse item o `model` precisa se configurado [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment), para saber a relação de campos que podem ser atualizados com essa técnica (`fill`)

```
protected $fillable = ['valor','proprietario','nome'];
```

<sub>**Observação:** nessa maneira o método `save()` é obrigatório ser chamado para salvar os dados na tabela.</sub>

---

*2) Maneira:*

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    if ($property) 
    {
        $property->update($request->except(['_token']));
    }
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}
```

---

*3) Maneira:*

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    if ($property)
    {
        $property->valor = $request->get('valor');
        $property->proprietario = $request->get('proprietario');
        $property->nome = $request->get('nome');
        $property->save();
    }
    return redirect()->action('PropertyController@index');
}
```

Comment: Agora esta dando a msg: MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 445:
_token

Comment: @Marcelo então use assim `$request->except(['_token'])` já fiz a edição

Comment: @Marcelo se tiver dando erro e mais campos adicione o no array `$request->except(['_token','outro nome'])`; e você configurou `$fillable` do seu model?

Comment: Usando a segunda maneira retornou: nome

Comment: @Marcelo eu não entendi, seguinte coloque na sua pergunta o seu model e também a estrutura da sua tabela por favor?

Comment: Meu model está vazio.

Comment: Era o model, coloquei protected $fillable = array('nome', 'proprietario', 'valor'); e funcionou.

Comment: @Marcelo nunca use `model` sem configuração, fiz a edição na resposta.